# how can I know whether render reason is property changed or state changed in react hook function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a displayer component implemented by react hook. The displayer component receives a set of records by property named 'rows'. It has two buttons used to show previous or next one, so I use a state named 'index' represents the current row no.

It is easy to show prev/next one by decrease or increase the state 'index'.
But when its rows changed, I want reset index to zero. How can I get the right condition without saving a copy of the rows to compare them?

```
interface row {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
interface tableProps {
  rows: row[];
}
const Shower: React.FC<tableProps> = (props) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  // when should I reset the index to zero when receiving a new property rows?
  return <div>  
    <button disabled={!(index > 0)} onClick={() => setIndex(index - 1)}>Prev</button>
    <span>{props.rows[index].id}:{props.rows[index].name}</span>
    <button disabled={!(index + 1 < props.rows.length)} onClick={() => setIndex(index + 1)}>Prev</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useEffect`

```
......

import {useEffect} from 'react'
....

useEffect(()=>{
   setIndex(0)
},[props.rows])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `useEffect` (see [docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)) in that case:

```
const Shower: React.FC<tableProps> = (props) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

 useEffect(() => {
   setIndex(0)
 },[props.rows])

  // when should I reset the index to zero when receiving a new property rows?
  return <div>  
    <button disabled={!(index > 0)} onClick={() => setIndex(index - 1)}>Prev</button>
    <span>{props.rows[index].id}:{props.rows[index].name}</span>
    <button disabled={!(index + 1 < props.rows.length)} onClick={() => setIndex(index + 1)}>Prev</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use `useEffect`, like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Shower = (props) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

    useEffect(() => {
       setIndex(0)
    }, [props.rows.length]) 

     // ... rest of the code
    }
}
```

on the code above, whenever the length of the rows changes it will reet the index to 0. of course you can use whatever variable and not just `props.rows.length`.

Just remember that the second paramteter on `useEffect` (inside array) will trigger the function on first parameter when those values change.